# pandas `to_html()` - how to make only specific rows bordered

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(index = ["Name1", "Name2", "Total"])
data["A"] = [1,2,3]
data["B"] = [2,1,3]
data
```

and I want to have bottom and top border for the entire `Total` row (including index). Currently I have the following:

```
s = data.style.applymap(lambda x: "border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid", subset = ("Total", slice(None)))
```

It doesnt work for index unfortunately and maybe there is more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition with [`set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) :

```
s = (
      data.style
          .set_table_styles(
              {"Total": [ #change the value here to choose another index/row
                  {"selector": "", #so the borders apply to the entire row
                   "props": "border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"}
              ]}, axis=1)
)
```

Or following your approach, you can chain it with [`applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap_index.html) :

```
s = (
      data.style
          .applymap(lambda e: "border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid",
                        subset = ("Total", slice(None)))
          .applymap_index(lambda idx: "border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"
                        if idx == "Total" else "")
)
```

Output :

[image]